# Syncing local code inside docker container without having container service running

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, docker-swarm

I have created a docker image which has an executable node js app.

I have multiple modules which are independent of themselves. These modules are created as a package inside docker using `npm link` command hence can be required in my node js index file.

The directory structure is as

```
|-node_modules
|-src
  |-app
    |-index.js
  |-independent_modules
    |-some_independent_task
    |-some_other_independent_task
```

While building the image I have created `npm link` for every independent module in the root `node_modules`. This creates a `node_modules` folder inside every independent module, which is not present in local. This is only created inside the container.

I require these modules in `src/app/index.js` and proceed with my task.

This docker image does not use a server to keep the container running, hence the container stops when the process ends.

I build the image using

```
docker build -t demoapp
```

To run the index.js in the dev environment I need to mount the **local src** directory to **docker src** directory to reflect the changes without rebuilding the image.

For mounting and running I use the command

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/src:/src demoapp node src/index.js
```

The problem here is, in local, there is no dependencies installed i.e no `node_modules` folder is present. Hence while mounting local directory into docker, it replaces it with an empty one, hence the dependencies installed inside docker in `node_modules` vanish out.

I tried using `.dockerignore` to not mount the `node_modules` folder but it didn't work. Also, keeping empty `node_modules` in local also doesn't work.

I also tried using docker-compose to keep volumes synced and hide out `node_modules` from it, but I think this only syncs when the docker is running with any server i.e docker container keeps running.

This is the docker-compose.yml I used

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "2"

services:

  demoapp_container:
    build: .
    image: demoapp
    volumes:
      - "./src:/src"
      - "/src/independent_modules/some_independent_task/node_modules"
      - "/src/independent_modules/some_other_independent_task/node_modules"
    container_name: demoapp_container
    command: echo 'ready'
    environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
```

I read this [here](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) that using this it will skip the `node_modules from syncing.

But this also doen't works for me.

I need to execute this index.js every time within a stopped docker container with the local code synced to the docker workdir and skipping the dependencies folder i.e `node_modules`.

One more thing if it could happen will be somewhat helpful. Every time I do `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run` it prints ready. Can I have something, where I can override the command in docker-compose with the command passed from CLI.

Something like `docker-compose run | {some command}`.

Comment: BTW, what is this application you're developing? How does it work? If you run the application all the time using `docker run -v $(pwd)/src:/src demoapp node src/index.js`, maybe you should consider using `nodemon` (https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to have the application (and just the application, restart when you update your code).

Comment: This is something like I am developing some lambda function code here inside docker.

Just as lambda executes a file from start to end, the same way I just need to develop around 50 lambdas, which will be developed and run inside docker.

Comment: Ok, forget what I wrote earlier about the `nodemon`. That's helpful when you've got a service running. I'm under the impression that you're working on a container that will execute 'jobs' mainly.

Comment: Yes, that too I am developing them in docker.

When deploying to production individual applications will be set up and deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a docker-compose file but you're not actually using it.
Since you use `docker run`, this is the command you should try:

```
docker run \
    -v $(pwd)/src:/src \
    -v "/src/independent_modules/some_independent_task/node_modules" 
    -v "/src/independent_modules/some_other_independent_task/node_modules"
    demoapp \
    node src/index.js
```

---

If you want to use the docker-compose, you should change `command` to be `node src/index.js`. Then you can use `docker-compose up` instead of the whole `docker run ....`

Comment: Thanks, but I seem you got confused with npm link, the link you understood is created in opposite form i.e the src/node_modules contains the symlink to actual "/src/independent_modules/some_independent_task/node_modules" folder.

`docker run -it demoapp /bin/sh` this executes when the container is running. For a stopped container it does not give access to its bash.

Comment: anyway that folder is empty because you don't "unmap" it and its content is filled during the build process. You're confusing the `docker run` with the `docker exec` command. The `docker run` will create a new container and it'll keep running until you logout. If you want to execute commands on an existing container `docker exec -it $containerName /bin/sh`

Comment: Ya sorry I made a confusion here, `docker run ` will create a new container and run the commands but on mounting using -v with `docker run` fails and syncs `node_modules` folder.

For `docker exec -it $containerName /bin/sh` the container needs to be running. My container is stopped, i.e it gets stopped when a single process executes.

Comment: Why do you use the docker-compose if you then running it with `docker run`?

Comment: I need the code sync between local and container code.

I used the mount with docker run but it mounted local node_modules empty folder in the container.

Hence I used docker-compose to sync volumes and skip node_modules folder, but this also didn't worked as the container stops after every  run.

Comment: so... does it work now? did you check my last edits to your answer? If yes, I'd appreciate if you accept the answer